# kazoo restarted zookeeper, the watch threw an exception

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

My configuration:

zookeeper: 3.4.10

os: ubuntu 16.04

python: 2.7

kazoo: 2.3.1

The code I run in IPython:
[image]

When I restarted zookeeper, with `bin/zkServer.sh restart`, the shell shows the exception as below:

[image]

If I delete the watch and replace with a listener, the listener works well.

I don't know why, and I read the info from google and github/kazoo, but I found no explanation of how to solve the problem.

P.S.: Someone said because the session of the client connection expired and was lost, the session_id is not the same with the retry connection when the zookeeper restarts

Comment: if I delete the connection.py lines 244:
#if header.xid != xid:
            #    raise RuntimeError('xids do not match, expected %r '
            #                       'received %r', xid, header.xid)
then th code run well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is related to a bug that was introduced in 2.3.1 from the following PR:
https://github.com/python-zk/kazoo/pull/305

This is being looked into, and may be rolled back. In the meantime, try using a pre 2.3 version of kazoo.